# Nested queries for text matching in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I was wondering if there was a way to run a nested query for text matches I'm trying to run on a dataset of tweets I have. I have a table in BigQuery that has tweets I collected which discuss a variety of stocks and I want to segment that table based on words found in the text of each tweet.

I have a sentiment dictionary (Actually it's a group of tables where each table lists words associated with a feeling. There's one table for words that denote positive feelings, one for negative, uncertain, etc.), so what I want to do is something like the following:

```
SELECT text AS bullish_tweets
FROM bigtweettable
WHERE text CONTAINS (SELECT words FROM table_x);
```

I just wasn't sure if BigQuery allowed that kind of query or if there was some function that could. Because these tables I'm using in my sentiment dictionary have anywhere from several hundred to several thousand rows each, it would be great to know this.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Tony, just to be clear, can you give an example of the schema of the Tweet table? Is it structured just like the Twitter Stream API JSON response?

Comment: Hi Michael, it is structured as a subset of the Twitter API JSON response. I have the following fields in my BigQuery dataset: created_at (string representation of the created_at field), source (string, either "Twitter" or "StockTwits", depending on which network), ticker (string of the ticker symbol) and text (tweet body).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way that I can think of to do what you're asking, unless you had the tweets already separated by word. If you pre-process the tweets to split out the words in input, you could create a repeated field that represented the words. You could then do the query:

```
SELECT text as bullish_tweets 
FROM bigtweettable
WHERE tweet_word IN (SELECT words from table_x)
```

Where the schema of bigtweettable would be something like
    Field : type : mode
    text : string : nullable
    tweet_word : string : repeated

If tweet_word was repeated you'd need to do the import as JSON, since CSV doesn't support repeated values. Alternately you could just pre-flatten and repeat the text for each word in the tweet.

Comment: Thanks, Jordan. If I understand what you're saying, it almost sounds like I'd be better off building a MapReduce process that would do what you're suggesting or it could look for my sentiment keywords (Stored in an array) and parse out tweets that way. Any rate, this is very helpful. Many Thanks.

Comment: That would work, but bigquery does supported nested records. You would just need to process the tweets before you add them to bigquery.